# How to declare a void pointer in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, void

How can we declare a void pointer in C#?

Answer (score 15):

`void* identifier;`

But it needs to be in unsafe as:

```
unsafe
{
    void* identifier;
}
```

And unsafe code has to have been allowed for the project.

Comment: Detailed documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/unsafe-code#pointer-types

Also read about unsafe code: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/unsafe-code

And how the garbage collection works since you are technically bypassing this. 

There are very few situations you need void pointers or unsafe code in C#, if you are here reading this with an intent to use void pointers to pass data to a method you are doing it wrong. If you're here to learn how things work then good for you!

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you mean in managed code, as your question is rather short to do anything but assume.

I think you're either looking for `IntPtr` or simply any `object` reference (which is the base type, and the basic equivalent of a null pointer - a reference to "something"). Unless you mean *null* pointer, in which case you're looking for `IntPtr.Zero`.

Answer (score 1):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb%28VS.80%29.aspx

> Visual Studio 2005Other Versions22 out of 43 rated this helpful - Rate
> this topic In an unsafe context, a type may be a pointer type as well
> as a value type or a reference type. A pointer type declaration takes
> one of the following forms:
>
> `type* identifier; void* identifier;` //allowed but not recommended Any
> of the following types may be a pointer type:
>
> sbyte, byte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, ulong, char, float,
> double, decimal, or bool.
>
> Any enum type.
>
> Any pointer type.
>
> Any user-defined struct type that contains fields of unmanaged types
> only.
>
> Pointer types do not inherit from object and no conversions exist
> between pointer types and object. Also, boxing and unboxing do not
> support pointers. However, you can convert between different pointer
> types and between pointer types and integral types.
>
> When you declare multiple pointers in the same declaration, the * is
> written along with the underlying type only, not as a prefix to each
> pointer name. For example:
>
> `int* p1, p2, p3;`   // Ok
>
> `int *p1, *p2, *p3;`   // Invalid in C#
>
> A pointer cannot point to a reference or to a struct that contains
> references because it is possible for an object reference to be
> garbage collected even if a pointer is pointing to it. The GC does not
> keep track of whether an object is being pointed to by any pointer
> types.
>
> The value of the pointer variable of type myType* is the address of a
> variable of type myType. The following are examples of pointer type
> declarations:
>
> Example   Description
>
> `int* p`
>
> p is a pointer to an integer
>
> `int** p`
>
> p is a pointer to pointer to an integer
>
> `int*[] p`
>
> p is a single-dimensional array of pointers to integers
>
> `char* p`
>
> p is a pointer to a char
>
> `void* p`
>
> p is a pointer to an unknown type
>
> The pointer indirection operator * can be used to access the contents
> at the location pointed to by the pointer variable. For example, for
> the following declaration,
>
> `int* myVariable;` the expression *myVariable denotes the int variable
> found at the address contained in myVariable.
>
> You cannot apply the indirection operator to a pointer of type void*.
> However, you can use a cast to convert a void pointer to any other
> pointer type, and vice versa.
>
> A pointer can be null. Applying the indirection operator to a null
> pointer results in an implementation-defined behavior.
>
> Be aware that passing pointers between methods can cause undefined
> behavior. Examples are returning a pointer to a local variable via an
> Out or Ref parameter or as the function result. If the pointer was set
> in a fixed block, the variable to which it points may no longer be
> fixed.
>
> The following table lists the operators and statements that can
> operate on pointers in an unsafe context:
>
> Operator/Statement    Use
> *
>
> to perform pointer indirection.
>
> ->
>
> to access a member of a struct through a pointer.
>
> []
>
> to index a pointer.
>
> &
>
> to obtain the address of a variable.
>
> ++ and --
>
> to increment and decrement pointers.
>
> - and -
>
> to perform pointer arithmetic.
>
> ==, !=, <, >, <=, and >=
>
> to compare pointers.
>
> stackalloc
>
> to allocate memory on the stack.
>
> fixed statement
>
> to temporarily fix a variable in order that its address may be found.
>
> C# Language Specification For more information, see the following
> section in the C# Language Specification:
>
> 18 Unsafe Code

Comment: The link you have provided nolonger points to the original page it has been archived here https://web.archive.org/web/20140911014448/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb(VS.80).aspx

Comment: Documentation is now here (2021): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/unsafe-code#pointer-types