# What is void** in C#?

Tags: c#, c, pointers, void

I'm looking through the source of a C# program that uses a library written in C. I came across this line and was unsure what it was:

```
cvbimUNSAFE.GetImageVPA ((cvbim.IMG)cvImg.Image, 0, (void**)&lpImageBits, &pVPAT);
```

What is an object of type `void **`? I did some Google searches and could only find information about `void*`, which is a pointer to a sort of catch all top level type, if I understood correctly.

Comment: I know this comes a bit late, but as a side note: Declaring a parameter as `void**` is also the C equivalent of passing a `void*` by reference or as an out parameter (`void*&`) and this is actually what the function `GetImageVPA` does (I happen to know the library...). So in the DllImport statement for `GetImageVPA` the safest thing to write would be `out IntPtr` or `out void*` (the latter requiring `unsafe` specification).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's a pointer to a pointer to something not specified. Basically, just think of it as a memory pointer to a raw memory pointer.

So, `int**` is a pointer to a pointer to an `int`, but `void**` is a pointer to a pointer, but it's not specified what that pointer is pointing at.

> I did some google searches and could only find information about void*, which is a pointer to a sort of catch all top level type, if I understood correctly.

Not quite. `void*` is a pointer to something, it's just not specified what that something is and should just be thought of as a pointer to a raw hunk of memory that you have to apply some structure to. For example, `malloc` returns a `void*` because it's returning a pointer to a raw hunk of memory.

Answer (score 2):

It's a void pointer. See this article for details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb%28VS.80%29.aspx

And you can take a look at this SO question for details on how to implement it in C#:

[How to declare a void pointer in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069448/how-to-declare-a-void-pointer-in-c)

On a side note, that method should be marked as unsafe if it's not.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I am guessing this library will allocate the amount of memory necessary to hold the image so it needs a double indirection so it can change the address `lpImageBits` points to.

Answer (score 1):

In C, it represents a pointer to a `void*` object. In other word, when you dereference it you get a `void*`.

I guess this is used because lpImageBits will be modified inside the function you are invoking.

Answer (score 0):

In C# `void**` is a pointer to `void*` pointer. Here is a simple example:

```
   public unsafe static void Main(string[] args)
   {
        int x = 1;
        void* v = &x;

        //dereferencing v, it prints 1
        Console.WriteLine(*(int*)v);

        void** vtp = &v;
        //dereferencing vtp, it prints 1
        Console.WriteLine(*(int*)*vtp);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

That's not C#.  It looks like C++.  In that case, a `void**` is a pointer to a void pointer.

Comment: It's c# that is using a c dll