# Getting Ptr Value of a Function

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have an API function in my application:

```
    <Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling:=True)>
    Private Shared Function GetProcAddress(ByVal hModule As IntPtr, ByVal procName As String) As IntPtr
    End Function
```

I just want to learn the pointer 'IntPtr' value of this function. How can I do it?

Note: I will show you the exact thing that I want in C++

```
void* fnGetProcAddress;
fnGetProcAddress = GetProcAddress;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1148177/just-what-is-an-intptr-exactly

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906152/what-is-intptr

Comment: Are you trying to find the location of the Win32 call `GetProcAddress`? (that is, is this a p/invoke signature?) EDIT: Hah - with the edit, I can see this is a pinvoke call - now what exactly do you need?

Comment: Is this question is possible duplicate of "What is IntPtr?" question? Are you kidding?

Comment: I want to get this address and write it in a BinaryStream as UInt32.

Comment: Sorry @MuhammedUğurNazlı I misunderstood your question - you have made it clearer since the edits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can continue using P/Invoke...

(Note, this is in C#, but easily convertible)

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procName);

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string moduleName);


var hModule = GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll");
var procAddress = GetProcAddress(hModule, "GetProcAddress");
```

Comment: I am trying it. Thank for ur answer :)

Comment: @MuhammedUğurNazlı Glad it's working, but please check Hans' answer below, as it makes some very good points!

Answer (score 2):

> I want to get this address and write it in a BinaryStream as UInt32

This is a **very** troublesome plan.  Short from the wrong data type, you have *no* guarantees whatsoever that the address you write is still valid when you read the stream:

- The DLL might simply not be loaded when you read the stream.  It does require making the LoadLibrary() call to get it in the process.  So at a very minimum you'd also have to serialize the DLL path.
- DLLs do **not** promise to get loaded at the exact same address again.  The load address embedded in the DLL header is merely a request, it is very common that the requested address is already in use by another DLL, forcing Windows to *relocate* the DLL.  That relocated address is not predictable.  A far bigger problem is that relocation is *intentionally* done on modern Windows versions.  A feature called Address Space Layout Randomization, enabled when the DLL was linked with the /DYNAMICBASE linker option.  It is an anti-malware feature, making it intentionally hard for malware to patch code.

Surely there's a better way to do what you want to do.  You however made the common mistake of not explaining your reasons, it is impossible to guess at.

Comment: @MuhammedUğurNazlı All of the points Hans makes here are absolutely correct; while what I put above should..."sorta work", it is **not** recommended

Comment: Actually, I am translating c++ codes into VB.NET. And c++ codes are working very well. So if this problem is there in c++ too, it doesn't matter.

Comment: This is the wrong thing to do in C++ as well.  That's you've been lucky so far does not constitute proof.  Especially given the drastically different VM layout of a managed program.  And managed programs having ASLR turned on.