# Size of pointer to member function varies like crazy

Tags: c++, pointers, visual-c++, sizeof

Got a really subtle problem. 
Got a class that compiled with MS VS 2013 c++ compiler, for 32 bit platform has the size of 4 bytes. The function pointer has sizeof 4 bytes. But when this class is compiled with this same compiler but included into different project to produce library, also targeted fo 32 bit platform, then the class has the *m_Function pointer occupy 16 bytes! Of course, when I'm instantiating this class from main project it thinks that class occupies 4 bytes and allocates this very memory size, while in reality it occupies 16 bytes and that causes memory overruns.

```
 class CC1
    {
    public:
        CC1();

        void (CC1:: *m_Function) ();
    };
```

I know that the size of pointer-to-member function can vary. But the qustion is - which compiler setting controls this? I don't care is it 4 or 16 bytes - just need them to be the same.  Struct member alignment settings are the same for both projects. /vmm /vmg options? No mention of them in compiler settings in both projects.

By the way, I tried building for x64 target and in this case sizeof *m_Function is always 8 bytes, from main and libray project.

Thank you.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/09/70002.aspx

Comment: Are you building the same way (IE debug vs release)?

Comment: probably different build settings (alignment, debug info, etc...)

Comment: What are you trying to do that requires them to be the same?

Comment: Just a guess: I'm guessing this is a /vmb or /vmg mismatch - these control the size of the pointer. Or you're specifying (maybe implicitly) /vmb and not following the rules?

Comment: @gnasher - this behaviour is causing memory overruns, because just 4 bytes of memory is commited, while object inside lib operates on its fields thinking about 16 bytes

Comment: Karoly Horvart pointed me at right direction - when I set the debug info from Debug Info for Edit and Continue to Debug Info for callee project, not for the lib itself, the sizes are now the same - 4bytes. However, as I tried to to confirm this behaviour and returned the Edit&Continue back, the size is 4 bytes in both projects still, So working like it should. Looks like Visual Studio compiler glitch. No memory overruns now, everything works... I hate such bugs) By the way - Edit and Continue - never got the reason for it)

Comment: This is one of the (many) reasons it's undefined behavior to cast a function pointer to `void*`

Comment: @southerton Be careful with such bugs as they're generally caused by ODR issues and as such they're very likely to be heisenbugs. Carefully check what works now with what was last checked into source control to check that you've actually got a fix and the bug hasn't just been hidden ready to bite you in a few weeks time...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[See here for docs page for /vm options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yad46a6z.aspx)

If you use the '/vmg' compiler option then pointer-to-member function will always be 16 bytes as you're effectively telling the compiler that it may not know the size beforehand and so has to assume the worst (virtual inheritance!).

If you use '/vmb' then the compiler must know about the inheritance pattern for the struct before use and so can use the most efficient method - in the case of simple inheritance this is 4 bytes.

Its likely that in some projects you've got '/vmg' set (which makes the class 16 bytes) and in others you dont (which makes the class 4 bytes).

/vmb is the implicit default - check your compiler command line for the libraries where this class is 16 bytes for /vmg

Comment: My issue was connected with Debug Info format. When I switched it From /ZI to /Zi (for callee project(?)) the problem dissapeared and pointer is 4 bytes in both the lib and exe project. Then I tried to reproduce this behaviour setting /ZI on again, but the pointer size is still 4 bytes. (And i didn't have /vmz or /vmb in my projects set).

Comment: However, I mark your answer because then I tried setting /vmz option on the lib, like you suggested, and with it the size of pointer became 16 bytes. So if someone else would encounter this problem that might be very well a solution for him.