# Why may there be a difference between union* and struct*?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, language-lawyer, unions

The C standard mandates that all pointers to `union`s have the same representation and alignment requirements.
It mandates the same for all pointers to `struct`s.

Thus my question:
**Why does the standard not mandate that pointers to `union`s have the same representation and alignment requirements as pointers to `struct`s?** (I would very much appreciate an example of an implementation taking advantage of this.)
Or did I simply miss the relevant text?

The relevant quote from the draft standard n1570 (C11 final draft):

> #### 6.2.5 Types § 28
>
> A pointer to `void` shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a
> pointer to a character type.<sup>48)</sup> Similarly, pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of
> compatible types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements. **All
> pointers to structure types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements
> as each other. All pointers to union types shall have the same representation and
> alignment requirements as each other.** Pointers to other types need not have the same
> representation or alignment requirements.

Comment: Isn't it the same reason why you cannot mandate that pointers to `int` have the same representation and alignment requirements as pointers to `char` ?

Comment: @Amir: There's a bit more to it than that. See my answer.

Comment: BTW: Will give this some time, maybe someone comes up with a really obscure implementation, some long-forgotten committee-discussion or something else equally enlightening/surprising.

Comment: @Deduplicator: When it comes to C89, the committee didn't even explicitly mention it ("all pointers to structure/union types") as a requirement. The reason for this "addition" is believed to be pointers to incomplete types of separate translation units. In my latest question I've shed a lot of information related to this requirement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither the [1989 ANSI C Rationale](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/rat/title.html) nor the [ISO C99 Rationale](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf) discusses this.

I doubt that there's any strong reason for the lack of such a requirement. Probably the committee didn't want to impose unnecessarily strict requirements. I also doubt that there are any real-world implementations where pointers to structs and pointers to unions *don't* have the same representations.

Consider, for example, that a struct can contain a single union member, and vice versa, so there's probably no good reason for an implementation to use different representations -- nor is there any good reason for the standard to require all implementations to use identical representations.

The reason all struct pointers "smell alike" is to permit the use of pointers to incomplete types. For example:

```
struct foo;

void func(struct foo *param);

struct foo { /* member declarations */ };
```

The compiler doesn't have to know anything about `struct foo` other than that it's a `struct` type to know how to generate a call to `func()`.

The same applies to incomplete union types. But an incomplete struct type cannot be completed as a union, or vice versa, so there's no great benefit in being able to assume that they have the same representation.

Comment: If there is no possible gain to be had from using different representation+alignment requirements for struct and union pointers as you say, there is one advantage to mandating there be no difference: Stronger guarantees for the programmer, which might allow him to be sure for a wider range of changes that his program is strictly conformant and thus highly portabe. (Even if there is a work-around, being direct and explicit is better...)

Comment: @Deduplicator: The committee had to consider the possibility that there could be reasons to use different representations that they didn't think of. Every requirement in the standard has potential non-zero cost on all implementers. The advantages of mandating the same representation for union and struct pointers aren't that significant.

Comment: @Deduplicator: If the committee followed the logic you describe, C as we know it, would cease to exist. The programmer already have the strongest guarantee possible: pointers to structs are not required to be the same as pointers to unions. What you're asking is not a guarantee, you're asking a narrow definition, which is not the same thing. Being strictly conformant and portable, is about following the rules. What you're suggesting is to change the rules by applying narrow definitions, which is definitely not the C way.

Comment: Would the compiler be allowed to impose an arbitrary minimal alignment for `struct`s, maybe to make such pointers more efficient on word-addressed machines? That would result in a significant difference between `struct`- and `union`-pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the Standard would not require that an implementation do so, an implementer may recognize the usefulness of having a type of pointer which might alias any of several types with different alignment requirements (e.g `uint8_t`, `uint16_t`, `uint32_t`, and `uint64_t`), but need only comply with the alignment of the type actually used for access (e.g. need only be 16-bit aligned when used to access a `uint16_t`).  Using pointers of a union type to access things that aren't actually objects of union type may seem strange, but C offers no other syntax to suggest that a pointer may be used to alias things of certain specific types in addition to the actual type used for access.

If the system used word addresses, it might be reasonable to say that all structures will be padded to a whole number of words and must be aligned on word boundaries, but imposing such a requirement on unions would make it impossible to use them for the above-described purpose.  On such a system, it might consequently make sense allow pointers to unions to identify locations at individual-byte boundaries (when *directly* accessing only things for which the alignment would be satisfactory) even though pointers to structures would be limited to word boundaries, and even though this might cause union pointers to be larger than struct pointers.