# Virtual inheritance and class function pointer size

Tags: c++, inheritance, mocking, virtual, fakeit

I have the following code, I am using MSVC:

```
template <typename T>
void CanMock() {
  class SimpleType {};
  static_assert(sizeof(void(SimpleType::*)()) == sizeof(void(T::*)()),
                "Can't mock a type with multiple inheritance or with "
                "non-polymorphic base class");
}

int main() {
  class base {};
  class derived : public base {};
  class derivedVirtual : virtual public base {};
  CanMock<derived>();
  CanMock<derivedVirtual>();
}
```

The `static_assert` in `CanMock` passes when called with `derived` but fails when called with `derivedVirtual`.

As far as I understand the assertion tries to compare the size of the class function pointer of a `SimpleType` with the size the class function pointer of `derivedVirtual`,

Now my questions are:

- I understand that the size of a `derivedVirtual` should increase because of the vtable pointer stored in it (right?), but why does the size of `derivedVirtual` class function pointer increases when inheriting with `virtual`?
- Why in clang the same assertion does not fail?

---

Just to give a little more context:

I am using `FakeIt` for testing. At some point I wanted to Mock a specific class, but I was not able due to the failing `static_assert` inside `FakeIt` source code. After some investigation I understood that the failure was due to the fact that the class that I was trying to mock was inheriting virtually from a base class. So I came with the above code, copy-pasted from `FakeIt`.

[Here](https://github.com/eranpeer/FakeIt/blob/49b27fec50c180870ab8b435907f12146dbf3063/include/mockutils/mscpp/VirtualTable.hpp#L260) is the line where I copied from.

So another question that came to my mind is:
which is the correlation between virtual inheritance and the ability to mock a class?

Thank you for your time.

---

Edit:

Here is the TEST_CASE that does not compile when I try to Mock the class:

```
TEST_CASE("Mock") {
    struct base {};
    struct derivedVirtual : virtual public base {
        virtual int A() = 0;
    };
    fakeit::Mock<derivedVirtual> mock; // This triggers the failing static_assert in MSVC but compiles in Clang
}
```

Is there a workaround to allow me to mock the class with FakeIt?

Comment: The standard says nothing about how virtual functions and virtual base classes should be implemented. Or the size of a pointer. Perhaps there is some tradeoff here between data size and code size?

Comment: On MSVC pointer method in a class with multiple inheritance (even without virtual inheritance) is also 16 bytes (like pointer to method in a class with virtual inheritance like `derivedVirtual`). This post is relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12006854/why-the-size-of-a-pointer-to-a-function-is-different-from-the-size-of-a-pointer.

Comment: "I have the following code". Did you write it? Did you take it from somewhere? If its from Catch2 source a link to source would help. Its online here https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2

Comment: The `sizeof` is not measuring any vtable pointer.  It's measuring the sizeof a "pointer" to member function (which really is not a pointer, it's implementation specific magic goo).  Since it is implementation specific and its implementation details are not specified by the standard, there's not much that can be said about what its size should be.  (I just woke up, so take my comment with a grain of salt.)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number, you are right, I just edited the question

Comment: @wohlstad The link seems very useful, thank you.

Comment: I tried the type traits, and derivedVirtual different from base and derived for these: is_aggregate is_empty is_literal_type is_pod is_standard_layout is_trivial is_trivially_constructible is_trivially_copy_assignable is_trivially_copy_constructible is_trivially_copyable is_trivially_default_constructible is_trivially_move_assignable is_trivially_move_constructible ... is one of them suitable for your use case?

Comment: @Eljay I am sorry but I don't understand how the type traits are supposed to help me. I edited my question to show more clearly what I want to achieve: I would like to understand which is the correlation betweek the mockability of a class and the size of its function pointers, and I would like to understand if there is a workaround for mocking `derivedVirtual` with FakeIt.

Comment: As per the FakeIt [documentation](https://github.com/eranpeer/FakeIt), at the bottom, it says what you are trying to do is not supported.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. Now I am surprised since in Clang the code inside TEST_CASE compiles and allows me to mock the class. The problem is only with MSVC.