# Reverse PInvoke using IDispatch::Invoke

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, reverse, intptr

I am doing a Reverse PInvoke from unmanaged C++ to C#. I do not want to use C++/CLI for this. I want to do this entirely with unmanaged C++ and C#.

I need to pass a pointer to a structure to C#. I read on this StackOverflow thread - [Just what is an IntPtr exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1148177/just-what-is-an-intptr-exactly) - that I can use IntPtr for doing this.

This is my managed method signature
    public int Start(string commandName, IntPtr a)
    {
    ....
    }

I am calling it from my native code using IDispatch::Invoke method. I constructed the DISPPARAMS like this

```
VARIANT pVarArgs[2];
BSTR bstrCommandName = NULL;
pVarArgs[0].vt = VT_INT| VT_PTR; // | VT_BYREF;
pVarArgs[0].pintVal = reinterpret_cast<int*>(context); //context is a pointer to a structure. 

pVarArgs[1].vt = VT_BSTR;
pVarArgs[1].bstrVal = bstrCommandName;    // Allocated elsewhere
DISPPARAMS dispparamsTwoArgs = {pVarArgs, NULL, 2};
//Invoke the method on the Dispatch Interface
hr = pDisp->Invoke(
                    dispid,
                    IID_NULL,
                    LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT,
                    DISPATCH_METHOD,
                    &dispparamsTwoArgs,
                    &varResult,
                    &exception,
                    &uArgErr
);
```

This is the error code I get - 0x80070057

My questions are as follows
    1.  Is there a better way to do Reverse PInvoke than using IDispatch::Invoke?
    2.  If IDispatch::Invoke is the best way to do this, how do I fix this error? I need to pass pointer to structures from native world to managed world.

Comment: You are heading for a world of hurt.  Use the #import directive in your C++ code.

Comment: reinterpret_cast<int*>(context);

I don't think you can pass a C++ structure to C# this way.

Have you tried passing simple argument such as integer or boolean?