# How to marshal a double pointer?

Tags: c#, c, pointers, pinvoke, marshalling

I am trying to use pinvoke to marshal a C structure to C#.  While I am able to marshal an intptr I cannot find the syntax to marshal a double pointer.  Both the int pointer and double pointer are used on the C side to alloc an array of ints or doubles.

Here is the C struct:

```
struct xyz
{
      int *np;  // an int pointer works fine
      double *foo;
};
```

And here is the c# class:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public class xyz
{
    Intptr np;  // works fine
            // double *foo   ?? 
   }
```

I am unable to find any instructions on how to marc

Comment: IntPtr is just a pointer: up to void*; so you can try marshaling "double* foo" as "IntPtr foo";

Comment: IntPtr doesn't mean "pointer to integer". MSDN: The IntPtr type is designed to be an integer whose size is platform-specific. It can point to any data.

Comment: Clarification: the C code is doing all the alloc/free of memory, so the c# side is blissfully unaware of all of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this description for what an IntPtr is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1148177/just-what-is-an-intptr-exactly). Have you tried using:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public class xyz
{
    IntPtr np;
    IntPtr foo;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to think that `IntPtr` is a pointer to an `int`. That is not the case. An `IntPtr` is an integer that is the same width as a pointer. So `IntPtr` is 32 bits wide on x86, and 64 bits wide on x64. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.aspx) makes all this clear.

The closest equivalent native type to `IntPtr` is `void*`, an untyped pointer.

So your class in C# should be:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class xyz
{
    IntPtr np;
    IntPtr foo;
}
```

To read the scalar value that `np` refers to call `Marshal.ReadInt32`. And to write it call `Marshal.WriteInt32`. But more likely, since this is a pointer, the pointer refers to an array. In which case you use the appropriate `Marshal.Copy` overload to read and write.

For the pointer to double, if the value is a scalar there is no method in `Marshal` to read or write the value. But again, it is surely an array in which case use `Marshal.Copy` to access the contents.

Comment: You are confusing IntPtr with an array of pointers.  The way to do this, I discovered, is: 
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 20)]        public IntPtr[] np;.               You may find this link helpful:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18647501/marshal-array-of-doubles-from-c-to-c-sharp

Comment: I'm not confused at all. Your ByValArray matches nothing in this question.

Comment: Let's read my answer again. I stated that "An IntPtr is an integer that is the same width as a pointer." And that "The closest equivalent native type to IntPtr is void*, an untyped pointer." From that it is clear that my understanding of IntPtr is solid.