# Marshal array of doubles from c to c#

Tags: c#, c, arrays, pinvoke, marshalling

Can someone please tell me exactly what I should write to marshal an array of double pointers between C and C#?

```
struct foo { double *abc[20]; };

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public class foo {  // ??? abc;   }
```

I have had many oblique resonses to 2 previous queries, and I have read another dozen or so questions here on this same topic, but I can't find in any of them a simple answer to this question.

Comment: This is the first time you've asked this question. All of your previous questions were utterly different.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the simple, straightforward answer to this question:

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 20)]
public IntPtr[] abc;
```

The trick is that, counterintuitively, you must use an IntPtr despite the fact this is an array of double pointers, not int pointers.

Comment: It's only counter intuitive if you don't understand what IntPtr is. The Int in IntPtr does not refer to the type of object that the pointer refers to. It simply indicates that an IntPtr is an integer. It is an integer that is the same width as a pointer. I tried to explain this to you in your very first question, but you accepted the other answer that contained no explanation and instead downvoted mine and told me that I was confused. I don't know why you ask questions if you then ignore the answers.

Comment: Sorry, but you still are confused.  In C, a pointer simply "points" (thus the name) to another value.  It is *not* the value itself.  Think of it this way: if you see a sign on the road that says, "This way to downtown..".  It is just *pointing* you downtown, but it is not downtown.  Here is a good tutorial on the use of pointers in C which I think you may find helpful: http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/pointers.htm

Comment: I have a rock solid understanding of pointers. I am not remotely confused. You on the other hand have asked a series of questions that indicate you think that double* is an array of pointers to double. And you still clearly don't know what the Int in IntPtr means. If you stop trying to teach me what I already know, I could help you learn.

Comment: An IntPtr is fundamentally different from an int. I've provided several links that should be helpful.  Here is a more basic introduction to concepts in C: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson1.html    Quite often people who know C++ or C# have only a superficial understanding of C.  But if you invest the time, I think the core C concepts will become clearer to you.  Nevertheless, I appreciate your efforts.

Comment: As I explained to you in a previous question, and IntPtr is an integer type that is pointer sized. Either 32 or 64 bits wide, platform dependent. It's typically used to represent unmanaged pointers or native handles. I have a quite solid understanding of C. Contrast that with the understanding shown by the person that wrote the code inside fooe!