# C++ Get Handle String Value

Tags: c++, string, casting, handle

I've got a `HANDLE` declared like this:

`HANDLE handle = new string("test");`

How can I get the value from `handle`?

Something like this:

```
string myval = (string)handle; //Cast doesn't work
```

Comment: What type is `HANDLE`?

Comment: `string myval = *handle;` ???

Comment: Do you mean [this kind of `HANDLE`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/902987/1858225)?

Comment: `HANDLE` could be absolutely everything, so your question is not answerable without wild guessing.

Comment: First off, what are you *really* trying to do? What you have posted almost certainly won't do it, but if you let us in on your intent we might be able to suggest an alternative. The immediate problem: Assuming HANDLE is an anonymous pointer that doesn't care what you point it at, (void *), `string myval = (string)handle;` didn't work because you have a pointer to string and that the cast will attempt to brute force the pointer into a string. You would need to cast handle to a pointer to string, and then get the value at the pointer, and that brings you to @Bathsheba's answer.

Comment: All this comes because the use of `SetProp(HWND hwnd, LPCSTR prop, HANDLE val);` I want to set a string value as a property of the `HWND` and then I need to retrieve that value with `GetProp`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `HANDLE` is either a `void*` or a `string*` then you can use

`string myval = *(string*)handle;`

or the clearer

`string myval = *reinterpret_cast<string*>(handle);`

If `HANDLE` is any other type then it's likely that the behaviour of your program is undefined.

Note that a value copy of your string will be taken.

Comment: Both instructions don't work. They stop my application from showing and stop the execution.

Comment: What is the type of HANDLE?

Comment: My fault, first instruction worked. Just forgot to check if it was NULL.Thanks.