# What is this `ConsoleHandle` HANDLE in my PEB?

Tags: c, winapi, internals, undocumented-behavior

I'm digging around in my process's PEB and I came across the so-called `ConsoleHandle` HANDLE in the nested RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS struct. So far, I've compared this HANDLE to the standard input, output, and error HANDLEs *and* the console HWND. It matches none of them and I'm at a loss for what this HANDLE is or represents.

I've also stumbled upon the fact that all these handles (minus the HWND) point to `\Devices\ConDrv`, so I'm also befuddled as to why `CompareObjectHandles()` only returns true for the pair of stdout and stderr. This makes intuitive sense from my normal understanding but now that I've found out about `\Devices\ConDrv` being the true backing kernel object for all these HANDLEs, I'm left wondering why this function doesn't return true in more cases.

1. What is this unknown `ConsoleHandle` HANDLE? Is it the default console screen buffer? In particular, what functions can be called with this HANDLE as a parameter?
2. If stdin, stdout, stderr, and this unknown `ConsoleHandle` HANDLE are all backed by `\Devices\ConDrv`, how come `CompareObjectHandles()` doesn't return true for any pairing of them? Any insight from kernel-land would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you read this: [Console Handles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-handles)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a Windows Handle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902967/what-is-a-windows-handle)

Comment: I've just now parsed over the links attached. The unknown handle could possibly be the screen buffer itself as implied by the "Console Handles" link (although I seem to remember the console's stdout handle also working in the call to `SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer`...). What interests me about this unknown HANDLE is that it's given in the process's PEB, so it has to have some notable significance, right? (especially with a name like `ConsoleHandle`)

Comment: The docs for [AllocConsole](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/allocconsole) say "A process can be associated with only one console" - so I would say that when AllocConsole is called, a handle representing that console is stored in the PEB.

Comment: @JonathanPotter, good point, I'm going to see if I can engineer a test to check this case. Going to be kinda silly since I'll need access to three processes' PEBs to sufficiently check (unless I'm overthinking this).

Comment: @JonathanPotter it seems you've got the right of it. Manipulating the *console* itself with `FreeConsole` and `AllocConsole` update that value in the PEB. Unfortunately this means there shouldn't be any functions to call with this HANDLE as none of those functions let you pass a *console* HANDLE, only a PID. Very cool!

Comment: What are you actually trying to do with this handle?

Comment: I know this is a bit late but I just wanted to know what the handle referred to. I like peeking into the PEB from time to time and the particular moment had me wondering what `ConsoleHandle` was. *shrug