# CUDA Virtual memory on Windows - what is the handle type?

Tags: windows, handle, virtual-memory, cuda-driver

From the CUDA driver API documentation:

> enum CUmemAllocationHandleType
>
> ```
> Flags for specifying particular handle types
> Values
>
> CU_MEM_HANDLE_TYPE_NONE = 0x0
>     Does not allow any export mechanism. 
> CU_MEM_HANDLE_TYPE_POSIX_FILE_DESCRIPTOR = 0x1
>     Allows a file descriptor to be used for exporting. Permitted only on POSIX systems. (int) 
> CU_MEM_HANDLE_TYPE_WIN32 = 0x2
>     Allows a Win32 NT handle to be used for exporting. (HANDLE) 
> CU_MEM_HANDLE_TYPE_WIN32_KMT = 0x4
>     Allows a Win32 KMT handle to be used for exporting. (D3DKMT_HANDLE) 
> CU_MEM_HANDLE_TYPE_MAX = 0x7FFFFFFF
> ```

What is the `HANDLE` type? i.e. what is its definition? And - can I define it manually, or must I include some Windows header for it?

Comment: If you are planning to support Windows, you'll probably have to include a Windows header anyway. That said, both HANDLE and D3DKMT_HANDLE are internally pointers.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev: What's the most minimal and innocuous Windows header I can include to have `HANDLE` defined?

Comment: `HANDLE` is defined in `winnt.h`. That said, it's a pretty sizable file, ~22000 lines. You can reduce the API surface with some `#defines`.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev: Make that an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Well, an answer to this question:

[What is a Windows Handle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902967/what-is-a-windows-handle)

suggests that:

```
typedef void* HANDLE;
```

may be a valid thing to do. I'm not sure that's the case, but will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

`HANDLE` is defined in `winnt.h`.

It's a pretty sizable file though, ~22000 lines. Minimal but hardly innocuous. You can reduce the API surface somewhat with #defines:

```
#define WINAPI_FAMILY WINAPI_FAMILY_SERVER
```

A precompiled header is your friend, if the compiler allows.

Comment: So, how do I reduce the surface with some `#define`'s?